# If an element is nested below divs, when do we need to care about div classes when selecting?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, dom

I often see `jquery` selectors of the sort

```
'$(#someid ul li a)'
```

But what if I know the `a` element will have a certain class at the point on the page where it exists?

Wouldn't it be better in that case to just do

```
$('a.someclass')
```

Trying to better understand at what level of specificity to make selectors and what situations can cause a lot of unneeded extra DOM traversal.

thanks,
Brian

Comment: depending on your code both may give the same result or different result so we cannot assume they are the same

Comment: Your question is too broad. What you are asking is actually "what CSS selector should I use?" I like using the least specific that does the selection correctly. Of course, you need to take into account that your HTML / CSS might get bigger and more complicated than at first you expected, and modifying the class/ID selectors can become a nightmare for testing. But this is only a general idea from me, not a convention, tradition or anything. So, I think your question doesn't really have a definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. If your links all got class `someclass`, you can just select it with `$(".someclass")`, which is even better.

But you have to be sure that this class doesn't exist elsewhere on your page or it will select that element aswell.

You could also use something like `$("html > body > #container > #someid > ul > li > a.someclass")` and the result will be the same. This is just a huge pain to maintain and also slower.

The performance doesn't vary much between CSS selectors, but is still present.
If you want to know more about selector performance, there is an article about that [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/optimizing-css-id-selectors-and-other-myths/).